# website not running in iis 7.5

Tags: html, iis-7.5

Bit of a IIS newbie so here goes: I am trying to run a website from iis 7.5:

[image: in the boerekneiter.com folder there is a file boerekneiter.htm]

The boerekneiter.com folder contains file boerekneiter.htm

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
this is the body
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately when i go to http://www.boerekneiter.com:8000/ chrome says:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.boerekneiter.com:8000
```

How can I fix this? do i need to install additional filters or components?

It is the only website i have in IIS:

[image]

Comment: On the local machine, this would be http://localhost:8000.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an IIS issue as much as a DNS issue.

www.boerekneiter.com is just the name of your site in IIS. If you have not set up DNS to point that domain to that server's IP, you won't be able to serve via the URL. As mentioned in the comment, you can test access to the server via the URL localhost:8000 or replace 'localhost' with the IP address of the server. You can also set up your HOSTS to direct requests for www.boerekneiter.com to the server for the time being.

Comment: localhost is not found either